# Extending SO Insights/Trends to other SE sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, trends

David Robinson's [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/08/01/flash-dead-technologies-might-next/?cb=1) yesterday about Flash being dead exposed me to the [Stack Overflow Insights/Trends tool](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=).  It's a very cool tool, but it looks like it's only pulling data from the Stack Overflow site (unless I'm blind and can't figure out how to pull data from the other sites).  Will this tool be extended to the other SE sites?  I'm a DBA so I tend to lurk around the [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site more often than not, and it would be interesting to see what trends pop up in our niche forum as well since I don't think the Stack Overflow data is representative of DBA-related questions (since a lot are often migrated over).

Comment: To expand on this, I think there are lots of cross-site patterns that may be interesting. A lot of these tools focus on Stack Overflow, neglecting that software developers and people who support software development are on other communities, with some having more cross-over or direct relations than others.